# Does magic intensity x2.5 in Master of Magic unbalance the game, eliminating the need for city development and army creation?

Tags: master-of-magic

I started playing Master of Magic two days ago. For the first scenario I chose Tauron and easy level. Initially the game was a bit hard, but I managed to kill two enemies before it crashed due to emulation issues.

For the second attempt I chose a custom hero: Nine books of sorcery, sorcery mastery and conjurer. Normal difficulty.

Then I captured the first sorcery node by magic spirit: moved it to node, summoned as many phantom warriors as I could, killed some guards, escaped an repeated the process. (I could summon a warrior only for 4 mana, so I restored MP by alchemy.)

This gave me enough of a power base to not have to worry about mana for low-level spells. I captured 5-6 cities and the same amount of power nodes without an army.  When I met Tlaloc, my power exceeded his about 10 times.

Does high magic intensity eliminate the need in city development and army creation? (The distant cities can be protected by summoned creatures with word of recall on them.)

Comment: I removed one question that is offtopic on this site

Comment: Try warlord with halflings. All other picks are just gravy once you get slingers at ultra-elite.

Comment: Or try 11 life books and start with Torin and planeshift for stealing nodes without fighting the guardians. Steamrolling has never been so easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Master of Magic Wikia entry for Nodes](http://masterofmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Node#Magic_Intensity) indicates the level magic intensity affects how much combat is focused around nodes. This doesn't mean that in the game is necessarily unbalanced by this, it means that you're playing a different style of game.

However Master of Magic is notorious for being an unbalanced game. People love this game because it flexibility.  You have the ability to customize your wizard and choose different play styles, but the effectiveness of builds varies widely. Many are overpowered. Random factors at the start of game will also make a big difference. A powerful rampaging wondering monster encountered early in the game can be a disaster, while starting near a lightly defended node can provide a huge advantage.

So I think the main reason why you were able to steamroll over everything in your second game was a fairly lucky start. This is the kind of thing you have to expect when playing Master of Magic. Increasing the magic intensity probably made exaggerated your lucky start, but it sounds like you would've done well regardless. If Tlaloc had gotten lucky with nodes in his start instead of you maybe you would have had a much different game. (Although the AI in Master of Magic isn't that great either.)